# Using reflection to set all of an object’s fields from SQL results

Tags: java, generics, jdbc, resultset, instantiation

The [*Java Tutorials* by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) include a page, [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html).

The code there shows how passing a [`Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object as an argument can be used with generics to define the type of an object being instantiated with `newInstance()`. Their example code goes on to mention in comments:

> Use reflection and set all of item's fields from sql results.

```
Collection<EmpInfo> emps = sqlUtility.select(EmpInfo.class, "select * from emps");
...
public static <T> Collection<T> select(Class<T> c, String sqlStatement) { 
    Collection<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    /* Run sql query using jdbc. */
    for (/* Iterate over jdbc results. */ ) { 
        T item = c.newInstance(); 
        /* Use reflection and set all of item's
         * fields from sql results. 
         */  
        result.add(item);
    } 
    return result; 
}
```

I am wondering what such code looks like to use [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) to populate an object’s fields with the results of a row from a [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).

➠Does anyone care to post an example of such code?

My interest is to see an example of reflection in action, and see how one might match up the members/properties of an object with the fields of the database row. Whether this approach is optimal or recommended is not the issue, so need for references to JDBC frameworks needed here.

Comment: That's not the way that I'd recommend doing it.

Comment: This depends largely on what you're expecting to come out in the `ResultSet`?  Is it a `Map` from column name to value?  Is it a long `String` of the results?  What other libraries do you have available (spring, gson, hibernate, apache commons, none)?

Comment: I added note at the end. I'm not asking for recommendations or discussions about optimal JDBC handling. I'm just curious to see some reflection code in action. When I saw that example scenario presented on the Tutorial page, I was curious to see what the omitted code would look like.

Comment: See Springframework's JDBC. Some of JdbcTemplate methods fill a target object with row values using reflection

Comment: Check Hibernate and EclipseLink, they also use reflection to populate objects.

Comment: Don't all ORM's use reflection for moving data to/from objects?